# PHP foreach iterate over the previous result

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, preg-replace

I have an array of strings which i want to insert in a text.

```
$text "some text";
foreach ($arrayStrings as $string){
 $new_text = preg_replace($old_string, $new_string, $text);
}
```

How can I set it so that each iteration will use the previous result for $new_text? I.e. at the end I get a text version which includes all new strings from the array, rather than just the last one, which is what i get now.

Thanks

Comment: `$new_text` -> `$new_text[]` create an array ?!

Comment: Why was the question downvoted?

Comment: Because it does not make sense. You iterate an array, but you do not use the array elements (`$string`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```
$text "some text";
$new_text = $text;
foreach ($arrayStrings as $string){
    $new_text = preg_replace($old_string, $new_string, $new_text);
}
```

Comment: `$string` is not even used.